# pandas same attribute comparison

Tags: pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'a', 'label': 'false', 'score': 10},
                       {'name': 'a', 'label': 'true', 'score': 8},
                       {'name': 'c', 'label': 'false', 'score': 10},
                       {'name': 'c', 'label': 'true', 'score': 4},
                       {'name': 'd', 'label': 'false', 'score': 10},
                       {'name': 'd', 'label': 'true', 'score': 6},
                       ])
```

I want to return names that have the "false" label score value higher than the score value of the "true" label with at least the double. In my example, it should return only the "c" name.

Answer (score 1):

First you can pivot the data, and look at the ratio, filter what you want:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='name',columns='label', values='score')
new_df[new_df['false'].div(new_df['true']).gt(2)]
```

output:

```
label  false  true
name              
c         10     4
```

If you only want the label, you can do:

```
new_df.index[new_df['false'].div(new_df['true']).gt(2)].values
```

which gives

```
array(['c'], dtype=object)
```

---

**Update:** Since your data is result of `orig_df.groupby().count()`, you could instead do:

```
orig_df['label'].eq('true').groupby('name').mean()
```

and look at the rows with values `<= 1/3`.

Comment: Gr8 idea to use pivot .. it's much simpler than what I thought! thankx

Comment: Just curious, is the dataframe a count from another dataframe?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean, but I produced this dataframe after applying groupby.size on the source data

Comment: thanks again .. I feel that the pivot way is more compatible.